# Maximum concurrent connections Azure Django

Tags: django, azure

I have a Django server deployed on an Azure medium instance. I just wanted to know the maximum number of concurrent connections that can connect to my server at once. Consider these as REST connections rather than TCP connections because our server has a REST interface.

Answer (score 0):

The number of concurrent connection is not artificially limited for Azure Virtual Machines, the actual number of the concurrent connections would depend upon the performance of your web service, the scalability of Django built-in web server and the reuse of TCP connection pool by your clients. You might want to test this using some [web load tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540.aspx).